# Undo A Change in RStudio

Tags: r, undo

I'm not sure this is possible, but I accidentally changed data within my data.csv file by writing the wrong command (i.e.- I replaced certain random text with NAs).  Is there a way to simply "undo" that change in the file (i.e.- recover the original text) or do I need to re-upload my original data.csv file and start over again?

Comment: Unless you still have the file open in the editor, no, there’s no way to undo the change. But since you mention RStudio in the title, I’m assuming that you’re editing the file from within the RStudio text editor? In that case, no problem — just hit “undo”.

Comment: I think I'm out of luck since I've done other things since (I didn't realize the error until I graphed my data) and the "undo" function in R Studio doesn't seem to be doing anything.